# Switching from Rhapsody to Eclipse (Papyrus) - UML model conversion?

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus, rhapsody

Our team has been using Rhapsody for developing UML models and c++ code for 10+ years, and we would like to switch to Eclipse and use Papyrus for UML modeling.

We have compatibility concerns: would the UML models (all class diagrams, state machines etc) created in Rhapsody be all portable to Papyrus/Eclipse easily? Rhapsody can export UML models into XMI files (UML 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 standards). My questions is: is Papyrus able to reconstruct diagrams from XMI files

If not, are there better alternative UML plugins that work in Eclipse?

The XMI file exported by Rhapsody contains only meta data of the models. Is there a quick way to port the entire project from Rhapsody into Eclipse? Anybody experienced the similar?

Your answers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do a test flight?

Answer (score 2):

First, I must mention that I am directly involved with Papyrus, especially with the brand new Papyrus for Real Time project, at Eclipse.

First to set expectations... Moving diagrams between modeling tools has always been an exercise in frustration... There have been "standards" over the years (e.g., OMG's XMI-DI), but none seem to have been fully successful and all have necessitated a manual review. Note that I have not tried with the latest version of UML (2.5).

Now the model semantics, however, have a tendency to be more portable, especially with more recent versions of UML. I am not sure which version Rhapsody pretends to support, so it would be difficult to comment further.

With the version of Papyrus that is currently in development (with a scheduled June 2015 release), the notion of "canonical" diagram has been added. This provides for automatic creation and update of some diagrams under certain condition. for example, many behaviour diagrams, such sequence diagrams and some structure diagram, such as composite structure, can be canonical and generated from the semantic model. However, layout would still need to be adjusted. Other diagrams, such as class diagrams, would have to be manually re-created.

As was mentioned in the comment to your question, trying it out would give you the best indication of how much work is involved.

Comment: Hi Blatorg: Your answer is very helpful and I appreciate it so much! Now I have some basic idea of what is possible and what is not possible in the current condition, without having to try certain things out in vain. I look forward to seeing your June/2015 release for the canonical diagram support that you mentioned. In the meanwhile, I'll try to do some importing experiment to see how it goes.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have specific question about Papyrus itself, you can also use its community forum at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/121/.

Answer (score -1):

I am interested in this topic and I did a simple research on it: in fact a connector between RSA and Ppayrus is already open source https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/835114/ it could be usefull to take a look at it and implement the same for Rhapsody.

I know that the Rhapsody XMI export did not export the graphical elements, you should probably then export them in a serialized format and mapping htem to papyrus diagram element.

other interested work but seems not to be free : modelbus https://www.modelbus.org/en/rhapsody.html which implement connectors with Papyrus EA and Rhapsody : could be also interesting to look at.

I am interested in your feedback if you did not let it down and do achive the mapping :)

Comment: There has been an effort to create a Rhapsody-to-Papyrus import facility, but I am unsure about the progress. I believe it is still internal and being tested. If that is of interest, you should let the Papyrus development team know...